# Why the JavaScript load function is not loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I work with Asp.net core Razor Page. I want JavaScript to load when the page loads, run when the page loads,no error is displayed on the console, my question is, did I pass the input parameters of the load function correctly?

```
public IActionResult OnGetShowComment(long id,int pageId=1 )
 {
  Comments=_CourseQuery.GetComment(User.Identity.Name,id,pageId);        
  return Partial("ShowComment",Comments);      
 }
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {                     
$("#listComment").load("/Course/ShowCourse?handler=ShowComment" + 
@Model.ShowCourse.Id);     
});
```

Comment: So you want to pass `@Model.ShowCourse.Id` to `OnGetShowComment`,and return a partial view?

Comment: Yes exactly, I think the problem is passing the entries right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass `@Model.ShowCourse.Id` to `OnGetShowComment` in url,You need to use `"/Course/ShowCourse?handler=ShowComment&&id=" +  @Model.ShowCourse.Id`,or it will call a handler which name is `ShowComment" +  @Model.ShowCourse.Id` with `"/Course/ShowCourse?handler=ShowComment" +  @Model.ShowCourse.Id`.Change your js like this:

```
$(function() {                     
$("#listComment").load("/Course/ShowCourse?handler=ShowComment&&id=" + 
@Model.ShowCourse.Id);     
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It runs when I do not send any parameters in the load function, but when I try to send the parameter, unfortunately it does not run at all, it is very strange to me, what could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried my answer,?The format of url in your question is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did not know how to use the parameter in the load function. I found out with your answer. Thank you very much. Yes, I used your solution exactly, but the load function does not run with the parameter, it runs without the parameter.

Comment: the premise of the answer is correct, but it's typo'd `&&id` and also `handler` is not a parameter to this action that @zeze provided to begin with.  That is, zeze, you aren't/weren't showing us the correct endpoint/action here.  However, assuming the `OnGetShowComment` is defined on the default controller for the `Course` `Area`, you should just be able to call/load a **GET** to `@($"/Course/ShowComment?id={Model.ShowCourse.Id}")` since `OnGetShowComment` is `{HttpMethod}{Action}` by convention.